# Play midi file or midi tone in iPhone with Xcode / Cocoa

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, midi, coremidi

I need to play midi file or midi tone in iPhone.

I have tested [MidiMonitor](http://goodliffe.blogspot.com/2011/02/pgmidi-updated.html). I think that I need to create a destination point on the iPhone to receive midi, but I don't know how do it.

Can you help me? Example source code would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Like @skinnyTOD noted, from iOS 5.0 on it is possible to use MediaPlayer.
First link the `AVFoundation`, and `AudioToolbox` frameworks to your project, then use this code:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

NSURL *midiUrl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"even voor mij" withExtension:@"mid"];
MusicPlayer player = NULL;
NewMusicPlayer(&player);
MusicSequence sequence = NULL;
NewMusicSequence(&sequence);
MusicSequenceFileLoad(sequence, (__bridge CFURLRef)midiUrl, NULL, NULL);
MusicPlayerSetSequence(player, sequence);
MusicPlayerStart(player);
```

This sets up the player with your midi file from bundle, and start playing.
Note that you will need to call `DisposeMusicSequence` and `DisposeMusicPlayer` when cleaning up the player.

Comment: Are there callbacks for when the file is finished?  Example: if I want to use several midis as background music in my game, I'd like to know when file #1 is finished, so I can start file #2, etc.  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting problem, I think it can be solved by using MusicSequence in a smart way. Anyhow, you might decide to ask it as a separate stackoverflow question.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I got a question though. Do you know a way to display the lyrics of the song like a karaoke?

Answer (score 2):

If you are still trying to sort this, iOS 5 includes the [MusicPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicPlayerServices_Reference/Reference/reference.html) API - it can load, play and create midi files. You'll need to also read up on the new [AUSampler](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2283/_index.html) AudioUnit.